# Creating new SMTP user in MailGun

Tags: smtp, mailgun

I have set up several clients' MailGun accounts and have always been able to add an SMTP user for a domain but am unable to in the latest account.

[Other account with option to add New SMPT User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLuCz.png)

[New account without option to add New SMTP User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEXeN.png)

Does anyone have any idea why this could be, please?

Comment: Which plan is the account on? Mailgun recently removed the ability to create new routes and users on their free tier.

Comment: How do I find out the tier? I know it's not a free account

Comment: Actually, looks like it could be a permissions issue

Comment: It WAS a permissions issue, all good